# Can I copy files automatically from a hard-drive when it is inserted?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, file-transfer

Is there a way to start coping all the files from a external hard-drive to another external hard-drive automatically when it's inserted?

I don't know the drive letter of both drives before. Is this possible without me being there?

Comment: What operating system are you using? I presume it's some flavour of Windows since you're talking about drive letters, but which version?

Comment: As @Scott said, I assumed Windows. Please clarify.

Comment: I and using windows 7 but I also have ubuntu 10.10 on my laptop.

Comment: Do you want both OS's to perform this capability?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've once used [Allway Sync](http://allwaysync.com/index.html) for exactly that purpose. It offers one-way sync and bidirectional sync for external drives.

This sync process can be triggered automatically when a drive is inserted. I guess you'd have to plug in the receiving drive first and then the source drive.

The tool is free, but with a (very generous) limited amount of files per month. Just try and see if it fits your needs!

Comment: This would be your best option.